# Clarifications regarding JSON and eval() with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

Following my code:

```
<?php echo json_encode(array(false, true)); ?>
```

How to do it with pure javascript to display the contents of the array that comes with a POST request?
I read that you need to use the eval() function to use JSON in javascript, there are security risks (XSS) if I use htmlspecialchars?

Comment: `JSON.parse` will work. Dont `eval`

Comment: A `POST` request sends data to the server. 'Pure Javascript' runs on the client. What exactly are you trying to display, and what does your 'code' have to do with it?

Comment: I mean, with pure javascript I make a request to the page with the code above. Let me give an example, how do I show the first false and the second true (client side )? Let me give another example, if instead of false and true there were two numbers, how would I show them (client side)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This is an example of the full javascript:

    $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
url: 'draw_search_results.php',
data: {example: example},
success: function (response) {
    var data = $.parseJSON(response);
console.log(data);
}
})
```

data contains the array you echoed out in php